# How to programtically queue a function for 48 hours (to change webform Author)

Tags: 6, rules, webforms

The code below changes the submission author to that of a user referenced in the webform (pulls username:uid). However now need this to change after 48 hours.

I am unsure how to effectively queue this for 48 hours before it runs or even if that is possible (I guess I will have to change the hook to "hook_webform_submission_update")..

I was thinking of rules but is there a hook which would help? Also if rules is the answer could anyone shed some light on how I can implement it into my code?

```
// change submission author to the submitted user lookup
function helper_custom_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {

    // get uid from user_lookup
    $user_lookup_cid = 1;
    $user_string = $submission->data[$user_lookup_cid]['value'][0];
    $user_string = explode(":", $user_string);
    $uid = $user_string[1];

    //change submission to be saved by user
    $submission->uid = $uid;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement [hook_webform_submission_insert()](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_webform_submission_insert) such that it saves `$node->nid`, `$submission->sid` and the current time to a designated table (e.g. *newsubmissions*).

Implement [hook_cron()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_cron/6) such that it goes through all records in the *newsubmissions* table, that are more than 48 hours old. For each such record, you should

1. load the submission by calling [webform_get_submission()](http://api.lullabot.com/webform_get_submission),
2. change the owner of the submission,
3. save the submission by calling [webform_submission_update()](http://api.lullabot.com/webform_submission_update),
4. delete the record from the *newsubmissions* table.

Implementing [hook_webform_submission_presave()](http://hook_http://api.lullabot.com/hook_webform_submission_presave) the same way as [hook_webform_submission_insert()](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_webform_submission_insert) will not work, because

1. `$submission->sid` is not yet set and
2. [hook_webform_submission_presave()](http://hook_http://api.lullabot.com/hook_webform_submission_presave) is also called for old submissions.

Comment: So to confirm do I wrap my helper_custom_webform_submission_presave function  in a hook_cron? Also wont this just run each time cron is ran not after 48 hours?

Comment: I clarified my answer. I hope this answers your questions from the comment.